# How do you make sure that on the order-pay endpoint checkout page you can display and change billing details

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

The My Account > Woocommerce Order menu has a Pay Now button if the order has not been completed. If you click the Pay Now button you will be directed to the order-pay endpoint checkout page. On this page I want to display a billing details form so customers can review and edit it. I haven't found the appropriate code to change the code in template/checkout/order-pay.php

[My Account > Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxmXg.png)
[Order Pay Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5izQv.png)

I want the order-pay page to be able to display and edit billing details.